# Modular Binomial Problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The solution to the problem of finding the primes $p$ and $q$ that have the following form:

$$
c_1 = (a_1 p + b_1 q)^{e_1} \mod{N} \\
c_2 = (a_2 p + b_2 q)^{e_2} \mod{N}
$$

Given the values of $c_i$, $a_i$, $b_i$, $e_i$ and $N$ where $N = pq$.

Can be found in [this writeup](https://www.ctfrecipes.com/cryptography/general-knowledge/maths/modular-arithmetic/modular-binomial) online. I follow the solution right up to the very last line where the author concludes that from the expression.

$$
a_2^{-e_1e_2}c_2^{e_1}-a_1^{-e_1e_2}c_1^{e_2}=a_2^{-e_1e_2}(b_2q)^{e_1e_2}+a_1^{-e_1e_2}(b_1q)^{e_1e_2} \mod{N}
$$

We can find $q$ as:

$$
q = \gcd\left( a_2^{-e_1e_2}c_2^{e_1} - a_1^{-e_1e_2}c_1^{e_2} \mod{N}, N \right)
$$

Perhaps because the expression has gotten so unweildy I've missed something simple but this seems like such a massive leap and there is no additional explanation.

Comment: $$a_2^{-e_1e_2}c_2^{e_1}-a_1^{-e_1e_2}c_1^{e_2}=a_2^{-e_1e_2}(b_2q)^{e_1e_2}+a_1^{-e_1e_2}(b_1q)^{e_1e_2} \mod{N}$$

$$a_2^{-e_1e_2}c_2^{e_1}-a_1^{-e_1e_2}c_1^{e_2}= q^{e_1e_2}\left( a_2^{-e_1e_2}(b_2)^{e_1e_2}+a_1^{-e_1e_2}(b_1)^{e_1e_2}\right) \mod{N}$$

$$a= q b \mod{N}$$
$$ab^{-1}= q \mod{N}$$